# vue-draggable not able to disable

Tags: vuejs2, draggable, sortablejs, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

I wrote a component that is shared throughout my application, in some places I need the dragging/sorting and some do not want it there. I pass a `prop` to my component called `disableDraggable` and based on that it should disable, unfortunately it does not do anything, how can I disable the draggable? 
I should note I tried both the options object syntax and also a simple `:disable` , here is the relevant code:

```
 <draggable v-model="copyOfQuestions" @end="$emit('updateQuestionsOrder', copyOfQuestions)" :options="{disable : disableDraggable}">  
// or :disable="disableDraggable"
      <v-card flat class="list_outer_block" v-for="q in questions" :key="q.question_id">
        <v-card-text class="pa-0">

          <v-layout justify-start align-center>
            <v-flex initial-xs px-2 py-3 class="handle minwdth-0" :title="$t('general.drag_for_reorder')">
              <v-icon class="text--secondary  text--lighten-3">$vuetify.icons.drag_indicator</v-icon>
            </v-flex>
    ....
        props: ['questions', 'disableDraggable'],
```

How can I disable the draggable functionality?

I should note that `vue-draggable` (what I am using) supposedly has the same api as `SortableJs`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be **:disabled** and NOT **:disable**.

```
 <draggable v-model="copyOfQuestions" @end="$emit('updateQuestionsOrder', copyOfQuestions)" :disabled="disableDraggable" >
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/17bdd4b8b2ab4f4df45dd76edf1afec864ec0936/example/debug-components/slot-example.vue

Comment: But just  `:disabled="disableDraggable"`, without prop options